# Access Flutter route outside MaterialApp

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a "fixed" custom app bar Widget that sits outside my Material App. I want this app bar to constantly sit at the top and the Widget views to change.

I would like this app bar widget to be able to listen to the routes being updated in the MaterialApp and react accordingly.

I think I need to use a RouteObserver but am struggling to have this app bar subscribe to any route events. I have tried broadcasting a stream to notify any widgets listening to it but this fires from the initState lifecycle hook so only is fired once and not received when calling Navigator.pop()

I have tried this https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: It would be nice if MateriallApp had an onChange event eg
new MaterialApp(
    onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings),
   onRouteChange (RouteSettings settings),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of handling the Route outside MaterialApp but this is how I have solved the problem.

I moved to use the Fluro navigator https://github.com/goposse/fluro which has given me a nicer route framework to use.

I now have a Static method that handles the Fluro route as well as broadcasting a view change Stream event to any components listening for my new Application.doRoute(context, path).

Inside the Application.doRoute(..) I add to my own custom _history List which has a context and path for each new Route. I can then call another static function called Application.doBack() which then pops the last item in the _history and broadcasts the view change Stream again.

I now can have root display list level Widgets react to changes within the MaterialApp.

Navigator.pushNamed and Navigator.pop() have now been replaced with Application.doRoute() and Application.goBack()